# Is it correct to say "the hem of your T-shirt is folded up. Let it down"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Look at the hem of my T-shirt above.

Is it natural to say "**the hem of your T-shirt is folded up (not nice). Let/put it down**" in everyday English?

Comment: It would help to know what you are trying to say.  "Let it down" or "Put it down" is a command.  Are you trying to command someone else to do it?

Comment: @stangdon, in some Asian languages, we don't often say "please". That may affect my saying

Comment: I would say 'turned up' for the hem of a garment accidentally doubled back like that.

Comment: "Let it down" makes it sound like there are cords holding it up and they should be untied.

Comment: If it is obvious what needs to be done, you can just say, "fix it."  This would sound quite rude if addressed to anyone but a small child.  To another adult, you could say, "You might want to fix that."

Comment: I agree with Canadian Yankee, but would go further. A tee shirt is an informal item of clothing. Nobody would ever try to "correct" this "wardrobe malfunction". So the natural thing to say is nothing at all. It will probably correct itself naturally with normal motion.

Comment: @James K - You are making an unwarranted assumption. I might *ask* a friend to alert me to anything unusual about my dress. Perhaps I want to look good according to my own standards. The OP's question is purely about what to say. It is not for you to prescribe people's behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Straighten [out]** fits well with things that naturally become crooked, crinkled, crenulated, or—as is the case here—folded. **Unfold** also works as a literal description.

**Let down** and **put down** sound more natural when the original arrangement is deliberate (e.g., to let down one's hair), which probably isn't the case with a T-shirt hem (except in sewing, where to let down or let out a hem is to remove the stitching).